# Hooking into WooCommerce notices after all notices have been generated, and before notices are printed and cleared

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What is the correct WooCommerce hook to use to modify notices after cart validation is completed and before wc_print_notices() is executed?

I’d like to customize the notices based on the totality of the notices to be printed.

The woocommerce_add_error filter runs as each individual error message is generated.  The wc_get_notices() function returns the notices up to but not including the current notice, and it’s impossible to know which iteration will be the last.

I’m using a commercial cart plugin that replaces the woocommerce_before_cart action hook with a plugin_before_cart action hook.

When I hook into this action with a priority of 9, wc_notice_count() == 0 and wc_get_notices() returns an empty array.

When I hook into this action with a priority of 10, wc_print_notices() has already been executed.

What’s the correct hook to use?

Also, what is the replacement for the wc_add_notice() function?
This comment from the CartController.php file indicates that the use of wc_add_notice() is to be discouraged:
* This filter will be deprecated because it encourages usage of wc_add_notice. For the API we need to capture
* notices and convert to wp errors instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize WooCommerce notices based on the totality of the notices to be printed, as the only hook available is `"woocommerce_add_{$notice_type}"` composite filter hook, that handle WooCommerce notices added via *wc_add_notice()* and *wc_print_notice()*.

Note: This composite hook will not work If the notices were bulk added via *wc_set_notices()*.

---

Does *wc_add_notice()* is going to be replaced?

The [*CartController* Class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Utilities/CartController.php) is part of StoreAPI, so only for  **WooCommerce Rest API**.

It discourages the use of *wc_add_notice()* in favor of [*NoticeHandler* Class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Utilities/NoticeHandler.php#L11) and all Classes located in [*StoreApi* > *Exceptions*](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Exceptions) folder.